# JavaScript storing data and iterating

Tags: javascript, object

While trying to store data inside an object and later retrieve it, I do not know the ideal way to store information inside javascript objects so that I can loop through the information.

I set up an object of arrays:

```
var resultObject = {name: [], function: [], group: [], photo: [], linkedin: []};
```

Then I loop through it:

```
function constructResultPage(data) {
    var resultHTML = "";
    var teamContainer = document.getElementById('teamInput');
    data.forEach(function(key,index) {
        resultHTML = "<div> + data.linkedin + data.photo + data.name + data.function + "</div>"
    });

    teamContainer.innerHTML = resultHTML

}
```

But resultObject is an object itself. Would you recommend that I store every array inside a single array to loop over the items one at a time? or is there in your opinion a better way of achieving this?

Comment: maybe you add some more data and what should happen with it. actually you treat the data like it has only one element in the array, but arrays are not limited to only one item.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - altough I am not sure I understand.

Comment: as it looks, is data an array with objects. the `resultObject` is an object with arrays. what in do you like to use?

Comment: Ah - I would like to use more objects because then I have an key to identify my data. Although when it comes to looping through the object I think I would use an array.

Comment: please **add that data** to make clear what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the help Nina.

What I had to do was create an empty array:

var data = [];

and then create objects inside of this array by looping through my data:

data.push({name: j.name, function: j.function, group: j.group, photo: j.photo, linkedin: j.linkedin})

Comment: Your data is inverted from how you need it shaped. You need an array of people, where each person is an object with name, function, etc. `var peopleArray = [{ name: 'bobby', function: 'cat lover' }, { 'name': 'janice', 'function': 'dominatrix' }]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try storing data in one array rather than four different. Consider running and experimenting with the snippet below.

```js
var content = document.getElementById('content');

// single array containing objects of similar kind
var data = [
  {
    name: 'Suzanne',
    job: 'Developer',
    something: 'S1'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    job: 'Developer',
    something: 'S2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Alice',
    job: 'Manager',
    something: 'S3'
  },
  // etc.
];

data.forEach(function(person) {
    var personInfoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    personInfoDiv.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + person.name + '; Job: ' + person.job + '; Something: ' + person.something;
    content.appendChild(personInfoDiv);
});
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```